# Word macro string comparisons

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word I am trying to compare the text in a specific cell in a table to a string and struggling.

```
Sub aMacro()
'
' aMacro Macro
'
'
Dim t As Table
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Dim Cell As String
        Cell = t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
        If StrComp(Cell, "Name") Then 'This one probably does as well but I haven't tested it yet
            Dim Name As String
            Dim Amount As String
            Dim Value As String
            Dim valueInt As Integer
                Name = t.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text
                Value = t.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text
                Amount = t.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text
                valueInt = 0
                If StrComp(Value, "Monday") Then 'this always activates, regardless of what I compare
                    valueInt = 5
                    Selection.TypeText Text:="This is here"                     
                    ElseIf StrComp(Value, "Tuesday") Then
                    valueInt = 4
                End If
            Selection.TypeText Text:="Name: " + Name 'These all print out with the correct values from the supplied tables
            Selection.TypeText Text:="Amount: " + Amount
            Selection.TypeText Text:="Value: " + Value                    
            Selection.TypeText Text:=valueInt
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I can get the values of the cells into variables but I cant seem to do any comparison on these variables. I also can't seem to use the .Value function that a lot of stack overflow posts suggest since it seems to be only available in Excel.

Does anyone happen to know how to compare the text from a table cell to a predefined string? I am using these comparisons to identify which tables contain the required data in a document so if there is a better way that would also be helpful, however I would still need to know how to do the comparisons for later use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post an example table or two so that we can reproduce your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to determine if the "Value" is Monday, this would be the syntax:

```
If Value = "Monday" Then
```

If you are trying to determine if Value Contains Monday, use Instr

```
If Instr(Value, "Monday") > 0 Then
```